# Regex to find successive words

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I want to display and compare he occurrence of all words after the word 'The' in Bash.

Example:

```
The next generation will be ruled by the smartphones. The next thing is interesting to watch.The question is how do we solve this problem
```

So the output expected is:

```
next                   2

smartphone             1

question               1
```

The following is the command I tried :

```
cat file.txt | tr A-Z a-z |grep 'the '  | cut -d\  -f2| sort |uniq -c|sort -nr
```

But this command is not giving me an inaccurate result.It giving me output of words which are not actually present after the word 'the'

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: cat pg1524.txt| tr A-Z a-z|grep 'the ' | awk '{print $2}'

Comment: *BUt this command is not giving me an accurate result.* What **does** it give you? What **should** it give you?

Comment: @melpomene . I am trying to find words after the letter 'The' from text file provided as input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Poi 'the \K\w.*?\b' file | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

or

```
grep -Poi 'the \K\w.*?\b' file | awk '{count[$1]++}END{for(j in count) print j, count[j]}'
```

Output:

```
next 2
question 1
smartphones 1
```

Comment: `\w.*?\b` can be written `\w+` for the same result.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte:Thank you, it's a little clearer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `grep` or `tr`; gnu **Awk** alone is sufficient for this task.

```
$ awk -F"[ [:punct:]]" '{i=1; for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) if($(i-1) ~ /^[Tt]he$/) a[$i]++}  END{ for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
next 2
question 1
smartphones 1
```

`if($(i-1) ~ /^[Tt]he$/` : If previous field matches `the` or `The` then store current field in associative array `a`